# Computing the binomial sum $\sum_{0\le i<j\le n}j\binom ni$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Find the sum
>   $$\sum_{0\le i<j\le n}j\binom ni.$$

My 1st attempt: replacing $j$ with $n-j$. So the expression turns out to be 
$$S=\sum n\binom ni-\sum j\binom ni$$
So adding the original and the final expression we get simply $S=n2^{n-1}$.

My second attempt: considering 3 parts:

Part 1: $i=j$, $\sum_{i=j}i\binom ni= n2^{n-1}$

Part 2: $i<j$ and $i>j$ they are equivalent, so we get $2S$

Part 3 : taking $i\in[0..n]$ and $j=[0..n]$ which gives $\frac{n(n+1)}22^n$

Combining all the parts I get $n^22^{n-2}$.

But none of my answers match with the given answer.

Comment: re your 1st attempt, if i am interpreting it correctly, if i=4,j=8,n=10, then (n-j) is not between i and n.  if this is not on point, please explain what you are doing in your 1st attempt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{0 \le i<j\le n} j \binom{n}{i}
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n j \binom{n}{i}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \sum_{j=i+1}^n j \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \frac{(n+i+1)(n-i)}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \binom{n}{i} (n^2+n-i(i-1)-2i) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(n^2+n)\sum_i \binom{n}{i} -\frac{1}{2}\sum_i \binom{n}{i} i(i-1)-\sum_i \binom{n}{i} i \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(n^2+n)\sum_i \binom{n}{i} -\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)\sum_i \binom{n-2}{i-2}-n\sum_i \binom{n-1}{i-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(n^2+n)2^n -\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)2^{n-2}-n 2^{n-1} \\
&= (3n^2+n)2^{n-3}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes I got it now thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @RobPratt very nice.

Comment: @user2661923, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply swap $j$ with $j$ and claim later that the sum on the right is the same as the one you started with, because $i<j$. You can rewrite the sum as:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n j{n \choose i}=\sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}\sum_{j=i+1}^n j=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(n-i)(n+i+1)}{2}{n \choose i}$$
Which you can disassemble into the sums of the form:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}&=2^n\\
\sum_{i=0}^n i{n \choose i}&=n 2^{n-1}\\
\sum_{i=0}^n i^2{n \choose i}&=n (n+1) 2^{n-2}
\end{align}

Comment: i understood your method and Rob Pratt's method but in my second attempt where I am going wrong, I didn't get it.

Comment: I think probably i<j and i>j are not equivalent is it so?

Comment: Actually we often do this in binomial summation questions so I thought maybe it could be applied here too.

Comment: Again, there are no three cases, there is only one and it is $i<j$ as it is said under a summarion sign